# Getting Error with getMap() in GoogleMap

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code error and I couldn't solve it and I wondered can you guys tell me what is wrong with my code.

This is my MapsActivity.java

```
package com.ite.googlemap;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

GoogleMap Map;
private static final LatLng ITE_COLLEGE_WEST = new LatLng(1.374935, 103.751998);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    try{
        if(Map==null) {
            Map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            Map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            Map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ITE_COLLEGE_WEST).title("ITE COLLEGE WEST"));

            Map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ITE_COLLEGE_WEST, 0));

            Map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);

        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

This is my activity_maps.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.ite.googlemap.MapsActivity"

class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
/>
```

This is what happen after I run the app when Messages Gradle Build Pop up

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2400Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAwareness1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCastFramework1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesInstantapps1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlaces1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerV4Impl1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAppindexing1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon1001Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
D:\GoogleMap\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:33:5-35:23 Warning:
    Element uses-permission#android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION at AndroidManifest.xml:33:5-35:23 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-79
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
D:\GoogleMap\app\src\main\java\com\ite\googlemap\MapsActivity.java
Error:(23, 86) error: cannot find symbol method getMap()
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 12.34 secs
>   Information:2 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: What's wrong with that?

Comment: I checked already but I don't find any duplicate stuff

Comment: why don't you post your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ite.googlemap">

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true">
</uses-feature>

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
</uses-permission>

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
</uses-permission>

<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES">
</uses-permission>

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION">
</uses-permission>

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
</uses-permission>

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">
</uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyD-k_r65Lu-yME0H2uW3gjNqGdgHoub4e4" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version">
    </meta-data>

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: This is my AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: *<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />* is there twice

Comment: Oh I just found it, Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2400Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAwareness1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCastFramework1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesInstantapps1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlaces1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerV4Impl1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAppindexing1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon1001Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
F:\Mobile Apps\Lab 15\GoogleMap\app\src\main\java\com\ite\googlemap\MapsActivity.java
Error:(23, 86) error: cannot find symbol method getMap()
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 2 mins 39.708 secs
>   Information:2 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: Still show an error after fixing the duplicate file

Comment: Does `MapFragment` have a method `getMap` ?

Comment: so why on earth do you expect it to work?  You can only use methods which exist.

Comment: I only follow what my assignment told me to do

Comment: Here is the assignment  told me https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MwNNZ_buZcjxl4dAhhma0Ds0xzvIDEuQ

Comment: @ScaryWombat  ^^^